# How can I make a public attribute for a class read only after initialization?

Tags: python, class, exception, readonly

For example:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
```

I want to make it so people can't change what `self.value` is after it's been initialized. So it would raise an exception if someone tried:

```
>>> c = Example(1)
>>> c.value = 2
```

I would like for it to raise an error or simply make it not possible.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I guess you need to override [`setattr(object, name, value)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) function in Example class

Comment: You can't. Anything you do can be worked around. Suggest you get over it and work on something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [property](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#property):

```
class Example(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value
```

Note that the value with still be writable as `example_object._value`, but prepending an underscore to an attribute name is a convention for telling other developpers this attribute is not part of the class public API and should not be used.